# Postfix + Courier virtual domain/users and maildir

Tags: postfix, courier

I have Postfix + Courier setup with virtual domains/users in MySQL, however, in /home/vmail these directories are not created so I get:

```
Apr  1 17:56:18 Lucid authdaemond: Authenticated: clearpasswd=xxx, passwd=xxx
Apr  1 17:56:18 Lucid imapd-ssl: chdir domain.com/user/: No such file or directory
Apr  1 17:56:18 Lucid imapd-ssl: user@domain.com: No such file or directory
```

I don't want to have to create /home/vmail/domain.com/user everytime before a new user can login. Is there a way to get the directories created automatically?

Answer (score 1):

By sending a welcome mail to user@domain.com these directories should be created automatically by Postfix (as far as permissions are granted in the parent directory).

Courier won't create missing directories itself.

But it should be clear that only by inserting a line in a MySQL-table neither Postfix nor Courier will create any directory automagically. One other solution would be to write a script that regularly maildirmake any non-existent directory found in the MySQL-table.